# JSON Body request to be sent as encodedurl postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a request which need to be sent in Postman as urlencoded value like in the following (I changed some value just to be sure is not sensitive data)

notifications%3D%0A%5B%7B%22clientFileUuid%22%3A%20%22123456-fc21-496d-96d4-dfgfdgdfgfgd%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2212345678%22%2C%20%22date%22%3A%20%222023-12-04T09%3A31%3A02.678871Z%22%20%2C%22event%22%3A%22ACCEPTATION%22%2C%20%22externalId%22%3A%20%22222222222-fc21-496d-96d4-a00bd36a0be0%22%7D%5D

The same need to be prepared in its decoded form which is

```
notifications=
[{"clientFileUuid": "123456-fc21-496d-96d4-dfgfdgdfgfgd","id":"12345678", "date": "2023-12-04T09:31:02.678871Z" ,"event":"ACCEPTATION", "externalId": "222222222-fc21-496d-96d4-a00bd36a0be0"}]
```

How can I prepare the decoded request to be sent in encoded form like above?
Is there any pre-request script we can configure to achieve the goal?

I tried with x-www-form-urlencoded variables, I tried to create a request in the pre-request but I'm not succeeding.
In general this:
notifications=[{"field" : "value"}]
it comes difficult to me to be configured.
Any idea ?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert to JSON, then `encodeURIComponent()` to URL-encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert to JSON, then `encodeURIComponent()` to URL-encode it.

```js
const notifications = [{
  "clientFileUuid": "123456-fc21-496d-96d4-dfgfdgdfgfgd",
  "id": "12345678",
  "date": "2023-12-04T09:31:02.678871Z",
  "event": "ACCEPTATION",
  "externalId": "222222222-fc21-496d-96d4-a00bd36a0be0"
}];
let encoded = encodeURIComponent("notifications=\n" + JSON.stringify(notifications));
console.log(encoded);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar but there is one error there, "notifications=" should be part of the request to be sent as per my statement above, like in the following: notifications=
[{"clientFileUuid": "123456-fc21-496d-96d4-dfgfdgdfgfgd","id":"12345678", "date": "2023-12-04T09:31:02.678871Z" ,"event":"ACCEPTATION", "externalId": "222222222-fc21-496d-96d4-a00bd36a0be0"}]

Comment: Added that to the code.

Comment: so change needed is let encoded = "notifications="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(webhook));

Answer (score 0):

First Define your JSON object, example below

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "id": "12345678",
    "date": "2023-12-04T09:31:02.67",
    "externalId": "222222222-fc21-496d-96d4-a00bd36a0be0"
}];
```

Convert JSON object to string

```js
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Encode the string as URL encoded format

```js
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent("notifications=" + jsonString);
```

Set the encoded string as the request body

```js
pm.request.body({
    mode: 'urlencoded',
    urlencoded: [{key: 'notifications', value: encodedString}]
});
```